# Statistics`NonlinearFit` not work in v11.2

Tags: fitting, compatibility

I have the following problem. I have to evaluate data using a nonlinearfit to extract certain values. Luckily there is already a mathematica notebook avaible online which i should use (according to my superviser). Now running this notebook doesn't work out for me using mm 11.2. I asked myself if have to rewrite some of the cells following the latest changes (like `NonlinearRegress` or `BestFitParameters`). On the other hand i have read through other forum posts and it seems as basically older notebook versions should run without problems despite the "old syntax". Maybe someone can help me in this matter? Many thanks!!

URL to the notebook http://www.ms.unimelb.edu.au/cgi-bin/wwwampc/dload.cgi?key=SHO+notebook

---

The code works basically for the first few lines, to be specific the import and sorting for the data works fine. Everything after that just generates a number as output (in the last line), no sort of diagramm etc.
Regarding the first line and the package error, deleting the first line already solves at least this error. Im not too experienced with mma and not sure if this leads not to any other errors. If im right, then i dont have to download any packages since everything i need is already in the basic setup included.

Like i said, i also noticed other commands which are also "outdated". But as ercegovac said there should be a backward compatibility.

Again im not really sure what the problem actually is, despite for the notebook not working at all.

Comment: Running the notebook is very 'vague' term. You have to be very specific about which particular expression does not evaluate. In general, the older notebook should run on latest mma (backward compatibility is usually maintained). So please be specific which cell did not evaluate in your notebook?

Comment: Opening the notebook, a problem is in the first line: << Statistics`NonlinearFit` the error being that it cannot open this package. It's not obvious what commands are related to this package. But to try it out, one would need data. There is a command: `NonlinearRegress` which is probably the old version of `NonlinearModelFit`.

Comment: @bills  One can find the compatibility information by searching `Statistics\`NonlinearFit\`` in the document. This is a package in _v5.2_.

Comment: @ercegovac Actually a number of packages is abandoned between _v5.2_ and _v6_ and as far as I know the backward compatibility for them is mostly not maintained… you can search *Compatibility* in the document for more information.

Comment: @xzczd You are right. My mistake.